# Google Drive API Share event

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I have an application that provides protection through encryption to files.
One of my clients requested that I shall add an ability to his Google Drive to protect documents once they are downloaded from his account.
The scenario is as following:
- My client uploads files (documents, excel sheets etc.) into his google drive account.
- My client send share invites to his peers.
- My client peers can view the files online, and they can download the files.
- When my client peers try to downloade the files, I need to capture a download event, protect the file and then continue with the download process.

I searched everywhere but cannot find an answer that is even close to what I need to acheive.

Your'e help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unless they are downloading the files through your application, you cannot intercept requests like this.

Your only option is to have them protected in Drive before they are shared/downloaded.

Comment: Hello Dan, This is very unfortunate. We are working with quite a few large organizations (some of them largest in the world in their field of expertise), and we get this request from quite a few. We do offer ways of pre-protecting the files before uploading, but they do not want to pre-protect the files as to be able to edit the documents online, and allow others to do the same. They would like to be able to protect these files when downloaded. Any plans to support this in the future? Any way to reach you directly?